# How to add custom domain to Google App Engine programmatically

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have created a django app using Google App Engine Flexible and would like the application to add custom domain programmatically.

Basically the application would use subdomain to separate multi-tenancy for example tenant1.domain.com, tenant2.domain.com.

Those custom domain will then have SSL managed by App Engine which help secure the application.

As I know there's already python client library here https://cloud.google.com/python/references/libraries but which one should I use?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have multiple subdomain, you need to use [wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#wildcards). Nevertheless, it is important to keep in mind that wildcard mappings are not supported for managed SSL certificates.

On the other hand, the library you need to use to create subdomains is the [Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/client-libraries) one. At [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.domainMappings/create) other link, you can try the API in order to see how it works.